# Creating a database connection in Python using SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I am new at SQLite in Python and I am trying to create a database connection.

I have the following as a datbase location:

```
E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf (i think)
```

The database is called FTHeader. However, when I try it i get an error saying `unable to open database file`

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show your codes? also, SQLite / MSSQL ?

Comment: This doesn't look like  SQLite database. My guess would be Microsoft SQL Server :)

Comment: Thank you both fo your quick responses!

Comment: It looks like ive made a schoolboy error and it is MSSQL so i don't think i can make a connection

Answer (score 0):

Pick [your poison](http://wiki.python.org/moin/SQL%20Server) from here and import the [module](http://haozes.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/mssqlservedatabase-access-in-python/) as db and the following should sort you, cribbing from [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/):

```
import adodbapi as db
import adodbapi.ado_consts as db.consts
Cfg={‘server’:’192.168.29.86\\eclexpress’,‘password’:‘xxxx’,‘db’:‘pscitemp’}
constr = r”Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Initial Catalog=%s; Data Source=%s; user ID=%s; Password=%s; “ \
% (Cfg['db'], Cfg['server'], ‘sa’, Cfg['password'])
conn=db.connect(constr)
```

You should now be connected to your database after replacing the Cfg dictionary to match your installation.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a database when completing a controlled assesment, here is the code that I have used:

```
import sqlite3

new_db = sqlite3.connect ('R:\\subjects\\Computing & ICT\\Student Area\\Y11\\Emilyc\\results1.db')
c=new_db.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE results1
(
    results1_name text,
    results1_class number,
    quiz_score number)
    ''')

#Class 1
c.execute('''INSERT INTO results1
VALUES ('John Watson','1','5')''')
```